# Path to image directory needs to include subfolders too

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

so I have this code that i am using to allow for livesearch of all my images using xml data sheet. What I am having trouble with now is being able to see the subfolder names being integrated into the file name of each image. The idea is that I will have a folder with images and within that folder many subfolders with more images. Rather than taking all those images out of the subfolders I would rather have the proper subfolder paths to be included in the filename so all the images in all subfolders can be included in the search.

Here is my current code:

```
$path_to_image_dir = 'images'; // relative path to your image directory


$xml_string = <<<XML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<images> 
</images>
XML;

$xml_generator = new SimpleXMLElement($xml_string);

if ( $handle = opendir( $path_to_image_dir ) ) 
{
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) 
    {
        if ( is_file($path_to_image_dir.'/'.$file) ) 
        {
           list( $width, $height ) = getimagesize($path_to_image_dir.'/'.$file);    
           $image = $xml_generator->addChild('image');  
           $image->addChild('path', $path_to_image_dir.'/'.$file);    
           $image->addChild('height', $height);    
           $image->addChild('width', $width);        
        }
    }
    closedir($handle);
}

$file = fopen('data.xml','w');
fwrite($file, $xml_generator->asXML());
fclose($file);?>
```

I think this line of code is the answer but have no idea how or where to add it and if any changes need to be made to the code.

```
foreach (new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path_to_image_dir)) as     
$file)
```

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks in advance everyone, cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you are already close. You can use that SPL Library to recrusively get the files. Example:

```
$path_to_image_dir = 'images'; // relative path to your image directory

$xml_string = <<<XML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<images>
</images>
XML;

$xml_generator = new SimpleXMLElement($xml_string);

$it = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path_to_image_dir));
foreach($it as $path => $file) {
    // you can use the `$path` key (which contains the path)
    // or another way is $file->getPathname()
    if($file->isDir()) continue; // skip folders
    list( $width, $height ) = getimagesize($path);
    $image = $xml_generator->addChild('image');
    $image->addChild('path', $path);
    $image->addChild('height', $height);
    $image->addChild('width', $width);
}

$file = fopen('data.xml','w');
fwrite($file, $xml_generator->asXML());
fclose($file);
```

Comment: if you want to explore other options and do some extra stuff you can consult other methods on the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/class.filesystemiterator.php)

Comment: What about adding a thumbnail? Any way to do that instead of height and width?     <img id="thumbnail" style="max-width:200px;max-height:200px;" src="/images/<?php echo $file_name; ?>" />

Comment: @WebEducate adding a thumbnail? what do you mean by that? you want an image inside an xml? just create an html `<img src="path_here" alt="" />` as a node value

Comment: @WebEducate like: `$image->addChild('thumbnail', "<img src='$path' alt='whatever' />");`

Comment: I meant adding a thumbnail to the search results. Instead of just a link to the image.